# Kafka Transactions: sendOffsetsToTransaction much slower than sendRecord

Tags: transactions, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I was timing some transactional code, to see where I was losing the most time.
The time taken is something like this 
**The comments have pointed out that this is due to send being async. Please read on to the follow-up question for a synchronous call. ( It is still slower :( )** :

```
producer.beginTransaction(); //0.08 ms
producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction( offsetMap, GROUP_ID);  // 105.96ms
producer.commitTransaction(); // 2.74ms


producer.beginTransaction(); //0.09 ms
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>( "dev-null", payload ) );// 0.16 ms
producer.commitTransaction(); // 28.37 ms
```

The timing is done like this:

```
long t0 = System.nanoTime();
statement_to_time();
long t1 = System.nanoTime();
long timeTaken = (t1-t0);
```

Why is there such a noticeable difference in time to send, sendOffsetsToTransaction and commitTransaction ?

fwiw: both `dev-null` and `__consumer_offsets` are triplicated topics with 50 partitions.

**Follow up:**
Can sendOffsetsToTransaction not be done in parallel with the send?  I ran a few more runs. ( Comment is execution time + commit time ):

```
// Asynchronous send. Flush cost is in commit call
producer.send(); // 0.16 ms + 28.36 ms 

// This call is Synchronous. Commit doesn't have flush cost 
producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(...); // 105.9 ms + 2.7ms 

// Synchronous send. Flush cost is in the send.
producer.send(...).get() // 26.1ms + 2.4 ms

// flush is done with sendOffsetsToTransaction. Commit cost double for two partitions
producer.send(...); 
producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(...);  // 128.26 ms + 5.40 ms 


// 5 partition write, no offset. commit cost is not 5x
producer.send(..., partition=0).get() ; 
producer.send(..., partition=1).get() ; 
...
producer.send(..., partition=4).get() ; // 28.3 ms + 2.52 ms

// 5 partition + offset write. commit cost is ~6x
producer.send(..., partition=0).get() ; 
producer.send(..., partition=1).get() ; 
...
producer.send(..., partition=4).get() ; 
producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(...);  // 127.25 ms + 11.8 ms
```

I can rerun these a few times, but so far kafka has stayed consistent with the numbers. The new questions which arise are:

1. Why does a sendOffsetToTransaction still take longer ( 105ms vs 25 ms )
2. ( Less obvious )  Why can multi-partition send(record) be performed in parallel, but sendOffset is in series to send(record) ? Similarly the commit ( transactionlog write ) is parallel for send(record) but adds up for offset ?
3. If (2) is true, Can i use a compacted-topic to track my own offsets? What would I be missing out on?

Comment: The send you invoke is an async operation which only puts the record into the memory, whereas `sendOffsetsToTransaction` is a sync operation that needs to wait for the offsets added to the transaction. I think it is definitely slower than the former one.

Comment: Try using `producer.send(record).get()` instead

Comment: Thank you. I've made the call synchronous and reported commit times as well. The offset writes still seem to be slow ( and performed serially ) when compared to the ( parallel ) record writes.